# How to make an INSERT into faster?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I created an Access tool that many people love across my organisation, however it doesn't work fast enough on larger clients.

Currently, when I run an 'INSERT INTO' query on my computer, it takes less than a minute - even on the larger clients. However, when I run it on a colleague's computer, it runs much slower - about 4 minutes.

The query code is fairly complex as it's running on 'LEFT JOIN-ed' tables to aggregate data, with SUMS, IIF statements, Nz statements and runs on the LEFT JOIN on 6 static tables and 2 queries.

Because of the confidentiality agreements around the code, I can't post the code here but I can describe it.

I could work to convert the 2 queries into a static table, then use the result of those, but is anyone aware of any other ways to make an INSERT INTO query work faster without altering the SQL code?

Also why is MS-Access slower to execute 'SQL INSERT-INTO' queries on some computers vs others?

I tried making adjustments to Virtual Memory settings and increasing page-files, but it doesn't seem to make a noticeable difference to the speed of running INSERT INTO queries, in fact, I think because my company uses non-SSD hard drives and doesn't allow partitioned hard drives, stuff runs slower as a result.

Comment: There are way too many variables when trying to compare 'this runs faster here than running there'. Are you familiar with SHOWPLAN? That may be a place to start. Can you rename tables and fields in your query, then post so we can at least see some idea of what you're doing? Make sure you select the smallest set of data before doing SUMS, etc. Any SQL Server tables involved?

Comment: Remove table names etc. and everything confidential and make a new question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. They may help you out with this. Otherwise google for "Insert Query performance tuning".

Comment: Also, here is an article full of performance tips... once opened, click on the link for 'Query Performance Tips'.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942824(v=office.12).aspx#odc_ac2007_ta_PerformanceTipsToSpeedUpYourAccessDB_QueryPerformanceTips

Comment: This is a really hard problem to solve and not really worth it -- who knows what the crazy user is doing on his computer (eg something as simple as having facebook open in the background could slow it down) --if you want a system you can control the speed of don't use local databases but instead use a data base server.

Comment: Don't "describe" the code. Instead, create an [mcve]. I.e. narrative descriptions often fail. Instead, try to create a runnable *sample* that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score -1):

FMS has an extensive write-up, on Optimizing Databases.

[FMS LINK](http://www.fmsinc.com/tpapers/faster/)